# Use strpos to search and then highlight the matched letters

Tags: php, string, post, str-replace, strpos

I want to perform a search on the $search string and then display the entire $search string with the matching letters highlighted.

This is the code so far:

```
//The user input
$user_input= $_POST['user_input'];

//The search
$search = 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.'; 

$match = strpos($search, $user_input);
echo '$match';

?>
```

Comment: Try with `preg_match_all` in php.

Comment: Why do not you use regular expressions? It will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php

    //The search
    $testar = 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.'; 

    $match = str_replace($_POST['user_input'], '<b>' . $_POST['user_input'] . '</b>', $testar);
    echo $match;

     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! But I had to write it like this:                                    `$match = str_replace($_POST['user_input'], '<b>' . $_POST['user_input'] . '</b>', $testar);`

Comment: @bello I write only a sample that help you to solve the problem, remember check the answer as correct.

Comment: @belio I edit the answer as you want, remember check it as correct ;-)